# Plugin Shortcode value in post

Tags: shortcode, array, post-meta, meta-value

Theme was output with function `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'some_value', true);` when I try with `die(print_r());` function there have some array containing values such as

```
[item_ticket_tailor] => Array
        (
            [0] => [custom_event id="3106" ][custom_ticket id="3220" show_price="true"]
        )
```

Question is How can I get `custom_ticket` value with `get_post_meta()` function

Comment: What to you mean by `custom_ticket` value? Do you mean the generated shortcode output, the shortcode text or the id-value?

Comment: Looks like the actual value is saved by some other mechanism and what you have here is a shortcode, maybe? How does the theme use this information?

Answer (score 0):

[shortcode_parse_atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_parse_atts)

> Accepts a string of shortcode attributes and returns an associative array of key/value pairs.

```
// UNABLE TO TEST THIS
// $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'some_value', true);
// $sc = $value [ 'item_ticket_tailor' ][ 0 ];

// TEST DATA - assuming the data is a string
$sc = '[custom_event id="3106" ][custom_ticket id="3220" show_price="true"]';

// pad some elements for a better parse
$sc = str_replace("[", " [ ", $sc);
$sc = str_replace("]", " ] ", $sc);

// convert the string shortcode to an array
$array = shortcode_parse_atts($sc);

// the last id is the winner, so custom_event id won't show here
// only custom_ticket id
echo $array[ 'id' ]; // 3220
```

---

**ALTERNATE**

```
$sc = '[custom_event id="3106" ][custom_ticket id="3220" show_price="true"]';

// split up the shortcodes
$sc = str_replace("]", " ", $sc);
$sc = str_replace("[", "[", $sc);
$shorts = array_filter(explode('[', $sc));

$custom_event_id = false;

// loop through each one
foreach($shorts as $short) {

    // get the individual attributes of the shortcode
    $atts = shortcode_parse_atts($short);

    // if the first item in the parsed array is `custom_ticket` then get the id
    if($atts[ 0 ] === 'custom_ticket') {
        $custom_event_id = $atts [ 'id' ];
        break;
    }
}

echo $custom_event_id; // 3220
```